# undefined method `its' for RSpec (Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Im At Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial Chapter 8 and I have got a problem. The test fails because of "its" method for RSpec is "undefined". Have you met something similar? what might be a reason? I have checked everything and is the same as in the book...

Here is my test code from user_spec.rb:

```
describe User do

 before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

 subject { @user }

 describe "remember token" do
 before { @user.save }
 its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
end
...
...
```

the result of tests running, it says: undefined method `its' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::RememberToken:Class (NoMethodError):

```
MBP:sample_app smi$ bundle exec rspec spec
/Users/smi/projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': **undefined method `its' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::User::RememberToken:Class (NoMethodError)**
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `subclass'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:219:in `block in define_example_group_method'
from /Users/smi/projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p594/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:325:in `module_exec'
from /Users/smi/.rvm/g.................
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You write the below as :

```
its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
```

as

```
expect(subject.remember_token).not_to be_blank
```

Read [`its` isn't core to RSpec](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509) and [Arguments passed to its](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/pull/306#issuecomment-758989) discussions. As you are using Rspec >= 3.0, so you got the error. Because in this version or higher `its` is not the part of Rspec core.

You can check the Rspec's current [One-liner syntax](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax).

Answer (score 6):

You need install `gem 'rspec-its'` - its provides the its method as a short-hand to specify the expected value of an attribute.

Comment: Also make sure to add `require 'rspec/its'` to your `spec/spec_helper.rb` (or equivalent)